# parameter postman-token couldn't find in SoapUI request

Tags: postman, soapui

I am getting familiar with both Postman and SoapUI. I already have a doubt. When I make a GET call with from the postman-echo service, I get slightly different responses shown to me in Postman and in SoapUI.

In particular, in Postman I get

```
"postman-token": "1ef2b330-3a46-4681-a304-d72f020cb194"
```

This field-value pair is not shown by SoapUI.

Can anyone explain me the apparent difference?

Comment: The difference of the `postman-token` when making a call from **Postman** and not seeing this from the SoapUI request? Use Settings > General in Postman and turn it off. Simple :)

Comment: In response? or in a request? Postman never return `postman-token` in response!!

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `postman-token` being added while you send a request from Postman. So, it's a custom parameter, you cannot expect it to be present with other tools.

If you check [Postman doc of General settings](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/launching_postman/settings/#general-settings) They have explained what is that param is for:

> This is primarily used to bypass a bug in Chrome. If an XmlHttpRequest
>   is pending and another request is sent with the same parameters then
>   Chrome returns the same response for both of them. Sending a random
>   token avoids this issue. This can also help you distinguish between
>   request on the server side.

You can disable it from Postman settings. Goto Settings > General > Send Postman Token header.